# uprade ubuntu cannot start

Tags: boot, grubrescue

I upgrade my ubuntu to 12.10 and after the installation, it restarts. But just After restarting, start up cannot proceed due to this pop up.
Error: file not found.
grub rescue >
.
Evrytime I shut down and turn on, The screen was blank with

Error: file not found.
grub rescue >

How to solve this?? Please help...

Comment: Do you have a LiveUSB/CD at hand? Otherwise it will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)(Detailed instructions are given on the page)

It solves most of the booting problems.

If it is unable to solve your problem then we will need more information to solve 
your problem

hope this helps!

Comment: The problem is The moment i start up my computer, The first dat appears is a blank screen with

Error: file not found
Grub rescue > __

 ( Thos ls are working in this command but i dont exactly know what to do here.)
Start up stucks on this screen till the right command or ls is type. please do you have any idea??

Comment: I know this is `grub rescue` error ..Just follow the instructions given on Boot-repair page and I think it should solve the problem.